# Symfony2 localhost working but have issue with 127.0.0.1

Tags: symfony, localhost

localhost:8000 works fine
127.0.0.1:8000 works fine

But when I added domain name:
http://mydomain.com.localhost:8000/ works fine
http://mydomain.com.127.0.0.1:8000/ not working

why?

Comment: For what practical reasons are you doing this? (mixing IPs and domain names). Maybe you can just create a local domain name like `mydomain.local` and add it to your hosts file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mydomain.com.localhost is not resolving for obvious reasons. For a quick fix, you could open up `/etc/hosts` and add an entry:

```
127.0.0.1 mydomain.com.localhost
```